# Dynamically creating clickable li in a ul and selecting the li content

Tags: jquery, html-lists, clickable

Apologies if this subject has been hashed through several times, i have read multiple posts on this and also tried out various approaches in jsfiddle.

Basically, i would like to access the content of the lis in the case below i add lis to the ul via a click on a button (in this case the clicks always add the same content- apple, in the real app, the content of each li is different. I would like to be able to click on one li and access the content of that particular li.

The code below gets me to the ul but not the specific li within the ul or the content of that li - any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <button id="testfood" type="button">Test</button>

        Fruits: <div id="fruits"><ul id="ul_fruits"  class="ul_fruits"><li>Fruit test li</li></ul></div>    </body>
</html>
```

This is the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#testfood").click(function(event) {
        $('#ul_fruits').append("<li><a href='#'>" + "apple" + "</a>" + "</li>");
    });

    $("#ul_fruits").click(function(e){
        console.log("click on #ul_fruits");
        alert(this);

        var index = $(this).index();
        alert("index " + index);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery's event delegation system. Basically, you get the `<a>` that was clicked on, and it works automatically for elements you add. Also, the `<a href="#">` will navigate which you probably don't want.

```
// bind it to the <ul>, run when an <a> is clicked inside the <ul>
$("#ul_fruits").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
  var text = $(this).closest("li").text();  // `this` is the <a>; get the text of the <li>
});
```

Comment: OP might want to add code canceling the click on the anchor tag inside the `<li>`, or remove that anchor altogether.

Comment: It makes more semantic sense for the anchor tag (A) to be the clickable element than the LI.

Comment: thanks for all responses. this was very helpful. I am not actually looking for the anchor tag and just need the li content - based on the above, the following code seems to work very well. Is there a down side to this? particularly in light of the @Diodeus comment about the (A) being clickable.        $("#ul_fruits").on("click", "li", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).text());
    });

Comment: also, sorry on the formatting of the code (i.e., not formatted), somehow my 5 minute time out for editing without figuring out how to flag something as code

Comment: @user1639465: Essentially they are equal in functionality. The only thnig to note is that doing `.on("click", "li"` makes the full `<li>` clickable rather than only the `<a>`.